# get project artifact id in custom library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a library that is intended to create documentation for my project. If the title value is empty in the project's configuration, the library should read the artifactId value from the project and use it as the title.

library: application.yaml

```
swagger:
  title: '@project.artifactId@'
```

but in my project title property fill by library artifact id
How can I set my project's name as the default value for the title property?